# Where can I go using a Portuguese temporary residence card?

Tags: visas, schengen, residency, south-african-citizens

Can I travel anywhere in the EU with a Portuguese Golden Visa temporary residence permit and my South African passport, i.e, without any Schengen visa?

Comment: Don't confuse the Schengen zone with the EU. The Uk, Ireland, Cyprus, Bulgaria, Romania and Croatia are EU members outside Schengen, and Switzerland, Iceland, Norway and Liechtenstein are Schengen members outside the EU.

Comment: @MLewis You can check https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y to find out if you need a UK visa. In general SA citizens typically need a visa to enter the UK, a temporary residence card for any of the Schengen countries makes no difference to visa requirements for the UK.

Comment: I know you asked about the EU, but you can also visit other countries outside of the EU (like Turkey) on the basis of your Schengen residence card. You still need a visa, but you can get it online in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

With a residence permit from a Schengen member state, you can travel to other Schengen member states, and sometimes to states which are in the process of joining the Schengen area, without a visa. The typical permitted stay is 90 days out of 180, as with other visitors, but it may vary with states that have not yet completed the process to join the Schengen area.

Comment: You might want to add that a visa for UK would be required. OP asked about EU, but also referred to Schengen visa as an example.